# How to read from the console log and if the error includes the string " up-to-data" to pass the 'if' cycle with no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, perforce

```
  p4.run("sync", filename, function (syncerror, updatedDate) {
            var logdata = console.log(syncerror);
if() {
}
    });
```

I'm not sure how to implement this.. if there is error which include the string "up-to-date" the "if" cycle needs to pass with no errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "read from console log"? Console log is a function which **writes** data to console, it returns nothing.

Comment: I need to read the data from 'syncerror' and if there is string "up-to-date" to pass out from the cycle with no errors. I need to exclude this error and to fail if there is any other error besides this one.

Comment: Why would you need `console.log` at all? Just check your `syncerror`.

Answer (score 1):

```
p4.run("sync", filename, function (syncerror, updatedDate) {
    var logdata = syncerror.toString();
    if(logdata.indexOf('up-to-date')!==-1){
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('not found');
        throw new Error(syncerror.message);
    }
});
```

I figure it out it this way. It works for me. Thanks for your hint Void!